# Add time delay between every statement of python code

Tags: python, win32com, sap-gui

Is there an easy way to execute time delay (like `time.sleep(3)`) between every statement of Python code without having to explicitly write between every statement?

Like in the below Python Script which performs certain action on SAP GUI window. Sometimes, the script continues to the next statement before the previous statement is complete. So, I had to add a time delay between every statement so that it executes correctly. It is working with time delay, but I end up adding `time.sleep(3)` between every line. Just wondering if there is a better way?

```
import win32com.client
import time

sapgui = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI").GetScriptingEngine
session = sapgui.FindById("ses[0]")

def add_record(employee_num, start_date, comp_code):
    try:
        time.sleep(3)
        session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/npa40"
        time.sleep(3)
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
        time.sleep(3)
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRP50G-PERNR").text = employee_num
        time.sleep(3)
        session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
        time.sleep(3)
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRP50G-EINDA").text = start_date
        time.sleep(3)
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMP50ATC_MENU_EVENT/ctxtRP50G-WERKS[1,0]").text = comp_code
        time.sleep(3)
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMP50ATC_MENU_EVENT/ctxtRP50G-PERSG[2,0]").text = "1"
        time.sleep(3)
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMP50ATC_MENU_EVENT/ctxtRP50G-PERSK[3,0]").text = "U1"
        time.sleep(3)
        session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMP50ATC_MENU_EVENT").getAbsoluteRow(0).selected = True
        time.sleep(3)
        return "Pass"
    except:
        return "failed"
```

Comment: What do you consider to be a "step"?

Comment: Have you considered using a Python debugger instead? `pdb` is in the Python standard library. It's [well documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) and has the ability to step through a program one line at a time.

Comment: If you want to step through the lines of code, use a debugger. There is one built in called `pdb`.

Comment: corrected, every line of code

Comment: You would be surprised how many steps that would actually be just for something that looks very simple on the surface like an assignment.

Comment: It is a Python Script which performs certain action on my computer. Sometimes, the script continues to next step before the previous step is fully complete. So, I want to add time delay at every step so that it executes correctly. It is working with time delay, but I will end up adding 'time.sleep(2)' at every line. Just wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: Thank you for telling us the X of your X Y problem. There should be a better way to do that. Please show us some of your troubling code!

Comment: Every line, or every statement? For example, if you write a two-line expression, like `result = function_with_lots_of_args(arg1, arg2, arg3,,` and then `arg4, arg5, arg6)` on the next line, where should the sleep happen?

Comment: @chundu: I agree with Klaus D., you need to show us some code -- there certainly is a better way. The general principle is to actually wait for whatever postcondition needs to be true for each step before starting the next one. I seriously doubt that you want to sleep *exactly* 2 seconds each time: instead you want to sleep "until it's ready" -- and you need to define what "it's ready" means for your program.

Comment: Also, @chundu: Could you [edit] the information from your most recent comment into your question? Without it, the question is easily misunderstood, and most of the answers you've received so far aren't really addressing your real problem as a result.

Comment: @chundu that can't happen unless you're using threads or multiple processes

Comment: @roganjosh Or using an event loop where the "step" is just starting a coroutine or starting an `after` function that does part of the work and calls `after` to continue, or similar things. (In which case sleeping is even worse than in a multithreading or multiprocessing program…).

Comment: @abarnert then I have something to learn too, but I have a feeling we're over thinking the issue and that the OP has misdiagnosed. I could well be wrong, though :)

Comment: @roganjosh Unless the problem is just a matter of `flush`ing a file or something, I'm pretty sure the real problem is waiting on some "background" task; the question is whether that's a thread or process, or a job sent to a thread or process or asyncio pool, or an undifferentiated chunk of a thread or process's work, or a chain of `after`-style callbacks on an async or GUI event loop, or…

Comment: In your edited question, what is that `session`? If whatever library it comes from has some way to wait for something to finish, that's what you want to do. But without any idea of what library that is, it's impossible to give you a more detailed suggestion.

Comment: @abarnert updated

Comment: @chundu: If your code is automating a UI task like sending a key (which is what it appears to be doing, although I don't know anything about the SAP GUI), then simply sending the keystroke doesn't mean that the corresponding operation has completed. Most likely there is something visible that happens in the GUI to indicate that the operation is complete, and what you should be doing is waiting for that to happen. Or perhaps you shouldn't be trying to script a GUI at all, and should instead be using some lower-level API? Unfortunately I don't know enough about SAP to actually answer that.

Answer (score 3):

The right way to do what you asked for is almost certainly to use the debugger, `pdb`.

The right way to do what you *want* is probably something completely different: find some signal that tells you that the step is done, and wait for that signal. With problems like this, almost any time you pick will be way, way too long 99% of the time, but still too short 1% of the time. That signal may be `join`ing a thread, or `wait`ing on a (`threading` or `multiprocessing`) `Condition`, or `get`ting from a queue, or `await`ing a coroutine or future, or setting the `sync` flag on an AppleEvent, or… It really depends on what you're doing.

---

But if you really want to do this, you can use [`settrace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace):

```
def sleeper(frame, event, arg):
    if event == 'line':
        time.sleep(2)
    return sleeper

sys.settrace(sleeper)
```

---

One small problem is that the notion of line used by the interpreter may well *not* be what you want. Briefly, a `'line'` trace event is triggered whenever the ceval loop jumps to a different `lnotab` entry (see [`lnotab_notes.txt`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/lnotab_notes.txt) in the source to understand what that means—and you'll probably need at least a passing understanding of how bytecode is interpreted, at least from reading over the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) docs, to understand that). So, for example, a multiline expression is a single line; the line of a `with` statement may appear twice, etc.<sup>1</sup>

---

And there's probably an even bigger problem.

> Sometimes, the script continues to next step before the previous step is fully complete.

I don't know what those steps are, but if you put the whole thread to sleep for 2 seconds, there's a good chance the step you're waiting for won't make any progress, because the thread is asleep. (For example, you're not looping through any async or GUI event loops, because you're doing nothing at all.) If so, then after 2 seconds, it'll still be just as incomplete as it was before, and you'll have wasted 2 seconds for nothing.

---

<sub>1. If your notion of "line" is closer to what's described in [the reference docs on lexing and parsing Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html), you could create an import hook that walks the AST and adds an expression statement with a `Call` to `time.sleep(2)` after each list element in each `body` with a module, definition, or compound statement (and then compiles and execs the result as usual).</sub>

Comment: Based on the comments, it's clear that the questioner doesn't want an interactive debugging solution, they just want to wait at each step for the previous step to be complete.

Comment: @DanielPryden But they have no idea _how_ to wait at each step, and the way they want to solve that (which is not a good solution, of course) is to sleep after each one. And this shows how to do exactly that without an interactive debugging session, while also (hopefully) explaining why it isn't a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

Anything you want to happen in a program has to be explicitly stated - this is the nature of programming. This is like asking if you can print `hello world` without calling `print("hello world")`.

Comment: This is true, but the reality in a language like Python is that *lots* of things happen without being explicitly stated. In fact, it's possible in CPython to use `sys.settrace()` to register a function which will get called for every line of code. You probably *shouldn't* do such a thing (let a debugger do that for you), but you *can*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best advice to give you here is: don't think in terms of "lines", but think in term of functions.

Answer (score -2):

use debugging mode and watch each and every line executing line by line.

Comment: Based on the comments, it's clear that the questioner doesn't want an interactive debugging solution, they just want to wait at each step for the previous step to be complete.

Comment: There's a Python debugger called pdb just for doing that!

Comment: Solutions dependent on the method of compiling used are considered inferior for a reason @SlahuddinChaudhary